# CasperJS "Syntax error: Parse error"

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I've just been starting to experiment with CasperJS for some testing purposes, but I'm apparently pretty crappy at it because I've isolated my code down to the very first task,:

```
"use strict";
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug'
    waitTimeout: 10000
});
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;

casper.start('http://foobar.com', function afterstart() {
    if (this.exists('.logo-link')) {
        this.echo('BOOYA! Page is loaded', 'INFO');
    } else {
        this.echo('Page didnt load, something went all screwy.', 'ERROR');
    }
});

casper.run();
```

run it through a linter, made the appropriate changes, and I still get this error:

```
Test file: Test.js                                                              
FAIL SyntaxError: Parse error
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: "SyntaxError: Parse error"
SyntaxError: Parse error                                                        
FAIL 1 tests executed in 0.103s, 0 passed, 1 failed.                            

Details for the 1 failed test:

In Test.js:0
uncaughtError: SyntaxError: Parse error
```

I've looked up some possible explanations, I added the phantom.cookiesEnabled = true, but I simply can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two best answers taken from similar question [getting more information from phantomjs "SyntaxError: Parse error" message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905664/getting-more-information-from-phantomjs-syntaxerror-parse-error-message) are:

1) run it with `node`:

```
node Test.js
```

2) use online syntax checker like http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma:

```
logLevel: 'debug' <--- Right here
waitTimeout: 10000
```

Comment: @user2493965: Explain what your error message is saying. I'm not too good with psychic debugging.